# What is the term for when 2 numbers cannot be factors of one another?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Lets say I have 2 numbers, A and B, In my scenario A cannot be multiplied by a integer constant (k) in order to make B. Is there a defined term or symbol for this to make it work?.

I assume this symbol does exist since vectors can be scalar products of one another, and it seems easier just to say something like B/A ≠ ℤ.

Comment: How about $A\not|B$?

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks!, Although I should look at a Wikipedia article just in case, What is the symbol called?

Comment: "Does not divide"???

Comment: Also, if you wanted to have A is not a factor of B AND B is not a factor of A,  you could say "A and B are not comparable",  in the partial order of "divides"

Comment: @barakmanos `\nmid` is usually preferred, $A\nmid B$ as in ajotatxe's answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you for the LaTex tutorial, I wasn't aware of this option :)

Answer (score 2):

This situation is usually written as $A\nmid B$

Comment: Beat you by $8$ seconds :)

Answer (score -1):

You can write that:

$\frac BA\notin\Bbb Z$